# How to broadcast a row to a column in Python NumPy?

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a row vector R and a column vector C. I want to add them to create an array A with height equal to size of R and width equal to size of C as follows: A[i,j] = R[i] + C[j]

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R + C[:, numpy.newaxis]
```

Does the trick for me.

For example

```
import numpy as np
r = np.ones(5)
c = np.ones(4) * 2
r + c[:, np.newaxis]
```

gives

```
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

Comment: Maybe in your example values `r = np.arange(5)` and `c = np.arange(4) * 10` would better illustrate that we get the desired output. :)

Comment: this is interesting.

Comment: thanks, this worked. do you have a solution for a related question I posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916950/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-increment-an-array-by-a-reference-while-broadca?noredirect=1&lq=1