# What's the most efficient way to increment an array by a reference while broadcasting row to column in NumPy Python? Can it be vectorized?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have this piece of code in Python

```
for i in range(len(ax)):
  for j in range(len(rx)):
    x = ax[i] + rx[j]
    y = ay[i] + ry[j]
    A[x,y] = A[x,y] + 1
```

where

```
A.shape = (N,M)
ax.shape = ay.shape = (L)
rx.shape = ry.shape = (K)
```

I wanted to vectorize or otherwise make it more efficient, i.e. faster, and if possible more economical in memory consumption. Here, my ax and ay refer to the absolute elements of an array A, while rx and ay are relative coordinates. So, I'm updating the counter array A.

My table A can be 1000x1000, while ax,ay are 100x1 and cx,cy are 300x1. The whole thing's inside the loop, preferably the optimized code doesn't keep creating big tables of A size.

This question is related to the [one I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915142/how-to-broadcast-a-row-to-a-column-in-python-numpy), but it's not directly applicable to this situation due to the way increment works. Here's an example.

This code does exactly what I want:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((4,5))
ax = np.arange(1,3)
ay = np.array([1,1])
rx = np.array([-1,0,0])
ry = np.array([0,0,0])

for i in range(len(ax)):
    for j  in range(len(rx)):
        x = ax[i] + rx[j]
        y = ay[i] + ry[j]
        print(x,y)
        A[x,y] = A[x,y] + 1
A
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

However, the following code doesn't work, because when we're incrementing an array, it pre-calculates the right side with the array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((4,5))
ax = np.arange(1,3)
ay = np.array([1,1])
rx = np.array([-1,0])
ry = np.array([0,0])

x = ax + rx[:,np.newaxis]
y = ay + ry[:,np.newaxis]
A[x,y] = A[x,y] + 1

A

array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

This solution works in terms of the correctness of numbers, but it's not the fastest, probably, because of np.add.at() function is not buffered:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((4,5))
ax = np.arange(1,3)
ay = np.array([1,1])
rx = np.array([-1,0,0])
ry = np.array([0,0,0])

x = ax + rx[:,np.newaxis]
y = ay + ry[:,np.newaxis]
np.add.at(A,[x,y],1)

A
```

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one leveraging `broadcasting`, getting linear indices, which are then fed to the very efficient `np.bincount` for binned summations -

```
m,n = 4,5 # shape of output array
X = ax[:,None] + rx
Y = ay[:,None] + ry
Aout = np.bincount((X*n + Y).ravel(), minlength=m*n).reshape(m,n)
```

Alternative one with `np.flatnonzero` -

```
idx = (X*n + Y).ravel()
idx.sort()
m = np.r_[True,idx[1:] != idx[:-1],True]
A.ravel()[idx[m[:-1]]] = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(m))
```

If you are adding into `A` iteratively, replace `=` with `+=` there at the last step.

Comment: Is there a way to skip zero counts?

Comment: @Aksakal So, what exactly do you need - Just the non-zero counts or do you need the X,Y indices as well?

Comment: @Aksakal Do : `A += np.bincount((X*n + Y).ravel(), minlength=m*n).reshape(m,n)`? `bincount` is the fastest tool to do binned summations, so you might want to keep it.

Comment: @Aksakal Check out `Alternative one`.

Comment: @Aksakal That's using slicing there. Read more here - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Comment: I'll check this alt code later, i couldn't make it work so far. It ran fast but the results were incorrect, maybe i'm adopting incorrectly

Comment: @Aksakal You might need to sort idx there. So, after computing idx, do : idx.sort(). Edited.